# Why does Java not give an error when I initialize a static variable in a constructor?

Tags: java, variables

I know that static variables are common for all instances and instance variables can be different for different variables. But, when I initialize a static variable in a constructor, the static variable can be different for different instances. Why doesn't Java give me an error when I do this?What is the point of static variables if it changes when I initialize it in a constructor?

Comment: Some singleton pattern used to initialize static variable in constructor which I find a good usecase for this question.

Comment: *"But, when I initialize a static variable in a constructor, the static variable can be different for different instances."* - no, it can't.

Comment: @lexicore It can

Comment: @adityabharadwaj how exactly?

Comment: @lexicore if I have two objects for a class car and those objects are Maserati and Honda.If I have a static variable named carColor which was initialized as "red" in the Constructor. The variable will be same for both Maserati and Honda but can be changed by doing this:-   
                                                  Maserati.carColor = "green";
now the carColor static variable for the object Maserati is "green" and "red" for the object Honda.

Comment: @adityabharadwaj This "static variable" will be the same for different instances, no matter what you do.

Comment: Try it out in an IDE.

Comment: Initialize the static variable in a constructor

Comment: @adityabharadwaj Here you go: https://ideone.com/ESTVEK.
Changing `carColor` from the constructor of one instance changes the value for all instances. QED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the value of the static variable in a constructor can make sense in some scenarios.

The first example I can think of is a `static` counter variable that counts the number of instances created for a given class. You'd increment that variable inside the constructor.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static int instanceCounter = 0;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        ...
        instanceCounter++;
        ...
    }
}
```

Another example would be lazy initialization of a `static` variable. You may want to initialize a `static` variable only when the first instance of the class is initialized (which means inside a constructor).

Comment: @adityabharadwaj if the answer has helped you, please click on the tick mark to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't Java give me an error when I do this?

Because it is not a Java error.   It may be a mistake in your program, but it could also be exactly what is required.  The compiler simply has no way of "knowing".

(A compiler that says "error" for something that is not an error is a really bad idea.  It only encourages people to **turn off** the error / warning messages.)

> What is the point of static variables if it changes when I initialize it in a constructor?

Static variables can be used for all sorts of things, and some of them include global counters (see @Eran's example) or "most recent" values or state changes.  Any of these could be updated in a constructor.